# Liveprofile, Push notifications, structure

Tags: android, http, push-notification

http://www.liveprofile.com/

I was wondering if anyone would be able to explain roughly how an application like LiveProfile is implemented?

How do the messages get pushed over the network from one device to another.  How do they know the address of the device they wish to send it to?  Is there a map of IPs and LiveProfile PINs?

Is it HTTP?  Just the general technology used would be a great help in improving my understanding of this aspect of Android and mobile engineering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about that specific app, but there are several possibilities out there.

One is Google Labs' C2DM: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/

Also, check this post. It has a very detailed explanation: http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Here is another one with useful info: http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/

Comment: Exactly what I am after.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

As a co-founder of LiveProfile I can shed a bit more light on what we've done.

LiveProfile was released before C2DM was available. Infact the market was fragmented and many were still using Android v2.0 and below. For this reason we ended implementing our own push based solution.

Our solution is a persisted socket to our servers at all times. When a user sends a message to another user, it gets routed through our servers and we decide who it should go to. If the persisted socket is connected then we push the data to them. If the user is not currently connected, we store the data in an queue and the user will receive all the messages on connect.

**Update:** A good resource is a talk from Google I/O 2009 which goes into detail about the battery life, how network / CPU effects it, etc. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OUemfrKe65c

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I guess by having this persistent connection then eliminates the need to store any maps of device addresses to PINs.  How is the persistent connection kept without draining 'any' battery life throughout the operation?

Comment: I updated my post with a link to a video from Google I/O 2009. Since we barely transfer any data over the network (other than KeepAlive's) the battery usage is VERY minimal.